# Display character " using ViewBag

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view, viewbag

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 with aspx.

I want from my controller to produce code at my view.

Therefore I have a line at my controller which is

```
 ViewBag.Chart = "var c = r.barchart(10, 10, 600, 440, [[55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2, 10], [10, 2, 1, 5, 32, 13, 20, 55]], { stacked: true, type: \"soft\" }).hoverColumn(fin2, fout2);";
```

However, when it shows at my code, it does not shows the character (") but instead it replaces it with a & quot;

What I can do in order to produce the character " at the code?

Comment: How do you display the content of `ViewBag.Chart` in your view?

Comment: @nemesv using this: <%: ViewBag.Chart %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `%=` instead of `%:`

```
<%= ViewBag.Chart %>
```

if you are using `%:` it is automatically HTML encodes your string while the `%=` does not.

Sidenote: it is not a good practice to emit JavaScript from your controller into your view...

Comment: @thanks a lot @nemesv! It worked! Thanks for the advice. Passing code from the controller to the view using the viewbag, is the only thing I thought to display my chart from the code. Can you suggest me any different approach, which is better? I am new to C# and the ASP.NET MVC

Comment: If you don't have anything dynamic in your JavaScript (and in your sample it is a static string) you can put in a separate `.js` and reference that js file in your view.

Comment: Thanks again nemesv. No, the numbers that I will use in the string should be dynamic, from my database...

Answer (score 0):

Hi try placing \ in front of the quote and before closing the quotes. It works fine for me

```
\"var c = r.barchart(10, 10, 600, 440, [[55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2, 10], [10, 2, 1, 5, 32, 13, 20, 55]], { stacked: true, type: \"soft\" }).hoverColumn(fin2, fout2);\";
```